# How do I Work with rho in prais winsten on r

Tags: r

I used `prais.winsten(model,data)$rho` and it returns `NULL`, I used `prais_winsten(model,data)$rho` but it flagged error, that no function called `prais_winsten`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Have you installed and loaded the library `prais` ?

Comment: Yes I loaded it.